# How to nest data regions for one dataset?

Tags: nested, ssrs-2008, subreport

This should be a common problem and easy solution.  But I have tried many solutions I've seen posted online and most were for previous versions of SSRS.  How can I nest one child table within a parent table?  I don't want to use subreports because of its inefficiency.  Instead I want to pass the parent key value to this child.  I have 3 levels.  This is what my structure resembles:

```
Employee1 
  Family
    Child1
    Child2
  Weight 
  Eye Color 
Employee2 
  Family
    Child1
    Child2
  Weight 
  Eye Color
Employee3 
  Family
    Child1
    Child2
  Weight 
  Eye Color
```

So the employee is the parent and then I want each employee to have these same attributes.  Similarly for family vs. child.  So I have a parent key field and a child key field in the same dataset that these link on.  How do I achieve this?

One of the problems right now is that although there is a parent-child relationship, I am filtering on the same field for all groups.  For example, the first level I am filtering on the "Employee" value.  Second level on the "attribute" value.  Third level the "Child" value.  So now if I filter the Employee level on "Employee", then the levels underneath it won't appear.  But if I don't filter it on anything then all records will appear in the Employee level, even if they are attributes or children.

Comment: According to the the title, you already have this data in one DataSet? Can't you just set up one table with a group based on Employee to display this?

Comment: Yes, all of the data is in one dataset.  But the problem is that I need to iterate through this dataset multiple times, one for each level.  So first it identifies all of the Employee Name records; on the second pass it gets their matching attributes.

Comment: Nested tables are automatically filtered by their parent tables. You can just drag a table with attributes into a cell on the one with employees.

Comment: Can you provide a more thorough explanation or URL tutorial?  It does sound simple, but nothing I've tried has worked so far.

Comment: And I have tried dragging an attributes table into this employees table, but it doesn't group the attributes.